# Mysql left join, get all right table columns and 2 columns from left table based on left table max id

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, left-join

I have a book series table (bs) that holds basic series info.
I then have a book series photo table (bsp) that holds the thumbnail for each bs based on the bs id. The bs can only have one thumbnail, so the bsp table gets an
insert for every photo update and when it needs to be displayed it gets the max id from that table. I now need to get every bs and the max id photo for it. My query returns all correct rows, but its not limiting to 1 per bs, its returning every bs/bsp combo. Here is the query:

```
select bs.*, bsp.Id AS BookSeriesPhotoId, bsp.Ext AS BookSeriesPhotoExt
FROM BookSeries AS bs 
LEFT JOIN BookSeriesPhotos bsp ON bsp.BookSeriesId = bs.Id
WHERE(
  SELECT MAX(Id) FROM BookSeriesPhotos GROUP BY bsp.Id
)
```

This returns 6 rows, 4 from the first series which had 4 photo updates and 2 for the second series which had 2 photo updates. I want it to return the max photo id per series, so it should only return 2 rows. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT bs.*, bsp.Id AS BookSeriesPhotoId, bsp.Ext AS BookSeriesPhotoExt
FROM BookSeries AS bs 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT bsp.BookSeriesId, bsp.Id, bsp.Ext 
           FROM BookSeriesPhotos bsp 
           INNER JOIN (SELECT bsp.BookSeriesId, MAX(bsp.Id) ID 
                       FROM BookSeriesPhotos bsp GROUP BY bsp.BookSeriesId
                     ) AS A ON bsp.BookSeriesId = A.BookSeriesId AND bsp.Id = A.Id
         ) AS bsp ON bsp.BookSeriesId = bs.Id
```